# Is there a way to reset the index in tkinter treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Is there a way to reset the index in the treeview widget in tkinter?
Using the selection() method I get the index of the currently selected child(I001, I002...).
Using the delete() method I delete the selected child, however when I add more data to the treeview widget, it counts the index of the new child as if the deleted child was never deleted.
For example, the only child's text in a treeview widget is "hi" and its index is I001. I delete it and add "hello". The index of "hello" will be I002 instead of I001(I want it to be I001).

Comment: You aren't required to use the auto-generated identifiers. When you insert items you can give any id that you want. Why do you need the automatically generated identifiers to be reset?

Comment: I want to replace the items in the treeview. I need the identifiers to reset for various tasks. How do I choose my own id?

Comment: If you want to replace the items - why don't edit I001 to "hello" instead?

Comment: I replace multiple items without knowing how many I will replace. If I have 6 items , I replace them with 4 items and then with 7 items,  it creates a problem when I try to identify each item afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that requires you to use the auto-generated ids. You can supply your own id when you add items to the tree by using the `id` parameter. You can generate your own ids by using a function which increments a counter.

It would look something like this:

```
counter = 0
def next_id():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return "Item%.4d" % counter

def reset():
    global counter
    for item in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(item)
    counter = 0
...
tree.insert("", "end", id=next_id(), text="this will have id Item0001")
tree.insert("", "end", id=next_id(), text="this will have id Item0002")
...
reset()
tree.insert("", "end", id=next_id(), text="this will have id Item0001")
tree.insert("", "end", id=next_id(), text="this will have id Item0002")
...
```

Comment: When I add the id parameter in the insert() method it makes the following error                            _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-id"

Comment: @Ofir: are you using python 2? I think this is a bug in older versions of ttk.

Comment: I use python 2.7. I discovered you need to use "idd" instead of "id" in that version of python.